# VARCHAR_FORMAT IN DB2 AND MYSQL

Tags: mysql, function, format

I have a line in the DB2 query as shown below

**varchar_format(col1, case when ord = 2 then '999.00' else '9,999,999,999' end)**

I'm looking for the same purpose function in MySQL.
I realized that this function doesn't exist in MySQL.
Is there any substitute function that can be used in MySQL?

Comment: Perhaps a generated columnhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: I've got the details on on the varchar_format() function https://www.ibm.com/docs/ko/db2-for-zos/12?topic=functions-varchar-format but this is in DB2. I'm unsure of the similar purpose function I can use in MySQL